# How to plot a line chart in ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js

I have created a dummy table and I want to plot a p/l column in type ' line'. Here's my code so far:

```
 var niftyProfit = [];
 var niftyProfitChartData = [];
 var sum = 0;
 data.forEach(function(obj) {
     niftyProfit.push(obj.profit);
 });
 for (var i in niftyProfit) {
     sum = sum + niftyProfit[i];
     niftyProfitChartData.push(sum);
 }
```

`obj.profit` is the p/l column data, but in a line chart. I want to populate the value, which I did in for loop for eg. consider `profit = [4,2,-3,-5]`, then my final array to populate in chart would become `[4,6,3,-2]`. How would I achieve this? Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkrh7/141/

Comment: why you tagged `angularjs` when there is no use of angular in fiddle or anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the jsfiddle with following changes and it is working.

**In the script**

```
var data = [{"profit": 345}, {"profit":-4}, {"profit":58}, {"profit": -30}];
//or you can use
var data = [{"profit": 4}, {"profit":2}, {"profit":-3}, {"profit": -5}];

populateChartData(data);
```

and added the Chart library as external resource that you can see as well. Then

Also i had added the canvas to the html

```
<canvas id="niftyTrackerChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

**Updated JSFiddle Link**
    http://jsfiddle.net/muasif80/zkrh7/156/

Have a look at this link [How to uses numbers array for line chart?](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#number)

This is saying if you are only using numbers then you have to define a labels array too for the x-axis.

Comment: I have already added canvas in fact am able to plot line but issue is its showing single line and taking only two first elements of array . My actual array after for loop means in (niftyProfitChartData) is       (28) [345, 340.55, 398.85, 408.3, 317.75, 245.05, 497.8, 427.95000000000005, 337.1, 638.5, 573.65, 417.09999999999997, 626.4499999999999, 592.4, 558.5, 734.7, 718.6500000000001, 703.0000000000001, 994.7500000000001, 926.7000000000002, 1053.0000000000002, 971.6500000000002, 926.8000000000002, 1099.7500000000002, 1224.8500000000001, 1325.45, 1486.3, 1661.05]

Comment: Ok let me take a look.

Comment: Ok now I have updated the answer. Have a look at the documentation link that i have added. You need to define labels array if you are only using numbers array rather than a points (x,y) array. The updated JsFiddle is indeed drawing all the points after I have added the labels array.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle link to http://jsfiddle.net/muasif80/zkrh7/155/ here i have added a way to generate labels array too using the loop.

Comment: one more question how to give color green to positive no and for negative red color for that single line

Comment: Ok will take a look.

Comment: You can have a look at this https://codepen.io/Tarqwyn/pen/QNzNVg and this https://github.com/bbc/Chart.Bands.js/

Comment: I have updated it the fiddle. But not sure why it is showing as green rather than red. http://jsfiddle.net/muasif80/zkrh7/156/

Comment: Thanx for help , for neg and pos color i used pointbordercolor. Now is it possible to show tooltip as actual data means, we ploted niftyProfitforChartData on chart but on hover it should show niftyProfit data as tooltip .Is It Possible? I tried several things but couldn't succeed.

Comment: What does that mean? Is not it already showing tooltips for the data points? I think its better you create a new question regarding this so that others can also look at it.